# Convert string to Control Type in C#?

Tags: c#, wpf, reflection

I have string property and Fill it with This Code :

```
  prop1= MyCustomPanle.GetType().ToString();
```

I use prop1 to keep type of Controls(wpf base control's and custom control's) .I keep this property and want to create type base on value this property. Something like This:

```
  Type ControlType=Type.Gettype(prop1);
```

But this `Type.GetType()` work only for variable type like int, string, etc.

**How convert string to control type?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass in the full `AssemblyQualifiedName` into `GetType()`.

You can get this from calling `GetType().AssemblyQualifiedName` on an existing instance of the type you want.

e.g.

```
var myControlTypeName = typeof(MyControl).AssemblyQualifiedName;
var myControlType = Type.GetType(myControlTypeName);
```

`myControlTypeName` above ends up as:

> MyNamespace.MyControl, MyProject, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null

But if you want it to be version neutral I beleive it can be shorted to the below and still work:

> MyNamespace.MyControl, MyProject

Answer (score 2):

I think you're looking for `Activator.CreateInstance`, this will create an object based on a type known only at runtime: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activator.createinstance.aspx

Comment: No, I just want type not create object!